# How to free memory allocation when a CCScene is replaced in Cocos 2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have Sprites, Spine skeletons, Audio objects in a particular Scene. When this 1st Scene goes and then comes the 2nd Scene, I want that all allocations done by 1st scene should be freed.

How to do that..??

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

If you released the 1st scene, and the all sprites and spine skeletons were addChild-ed to the scene (or the children of the scene) without any other references, the all sprites and spine skeletons would be released automatically. no worries about those.

If you preloaded audio effects, you should unload those audio effects.

But the textures of the sprites and spine skeletons wouldn't be released automatically. TextureCache keeps the textures for further loading. So you should call removeUnusedTextures or removeTexture/removeTextureForKey one by one.

```
cocos2d::TextureCache::getInstance()->removeUnusedTextures();
```

"[How to Optimise Memory Usage](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_optimise_memory_usage)" is a good document for investigating memory usage and TextureCache.